# azure apim user invitation link expiry date

Tags: azure-api-management

How many days the invitation link are valid for a new user from azure apim?.

I have invited a user from Azure apim management->User's list. The invitation link got expired for 2to 3 days and unable to reset the new password by the user and its getting "Error" page.

I just wanted to know how many days the invitation will be active or valid?

Thanks

Comment: I viewed Ms document and found no information about expire date. I also used Fiddler to try to get the clue but failed. I'm afraid that there's  no official document providing related message.

Answer (score 0):

According to search all of the document on internet, it seems there is nowhere in document mention about the expire date of the invitation link. Also as Tiny mentioned in comment, we can't find information about expire date in invite link and reset password request(although use fiddler to catch the request).

So I think it is difficult for us to know the expire date just from stack overflow. You can [raise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) a support ticket on azure portal to ask azure support team for this question. They can provide you official answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Seems there is no option to change expiry date for invitation links.